# implementing flipcard on click instead of on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have implemented a css flipcard effect, which works on hover using css. See css code below. However I want to implement the flipcard effect on click by using jQuery. I have tried everything but cannot figure it out.

Here is the javascript that I thought would work.

```
$('.flip-container .flipper').click(function(){
    $(this).css('transform, rotateY(180deg)');
});
```

Please see below for code that works with hover.

**html**

```
<div class="flip-container">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front artist-1">
      <!-- front content -->
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>You won</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

/* flip speed */
.flipper {
  transition: 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: #fff;
}


.artist-1 {
  background: url(http://img.bleacherreport.net/img/images/photos/003/556/940/edab30087cea36c0ca206fc61a4b10fa_crop_north.jpg?w=630&h=420&q=75) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make this work you need to remove the `:hover` rule on the `.flip-container` element in your CSS:

```
/* .flip-container:hover .flipper, */
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Then in your JS you need to toggle the `hover` class when the element is clicked instead:

```
$('.flip-container .flipper').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.flip-container').toggleClass('hover');
    $(this).css('transform, rotateY(180deg)');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/rsg59hbL/)

Note that it may also be worth changing the class name from `hover` now too, otherwise it may get confusing when you come to maintain the code at a later date

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to change your css from being triggered on `:hover` pseudo element to a class which you need  to toggle via jquery.

css

```
/* flip the pane when clicked */
 .flip-container .flipper.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

JS

```
$('.flip-container .flipper').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("flip");
});
```

here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t7t0t22x/1/)