# Reset old card flip when flipping a new card

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to automatically flip the old card back when you flip a second one?

I have this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/yu53sr8n/1/) which I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261931/implementing-flipcard-on-click-instead-of-on-hover) question.
I looked around the internet but couldn't find any solutions to this specific problem.
It might be similar to [this](http://www.bateauxtheme.com/elements/accordions/). Hope this could help :)

I'd like to add a button to manually flip the card back and forth.

the code

```js
$('.flip-container .flipper').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.flip-container').toggleClass('hover');
    $(this).css('transform, rotateY(180deg)');
});
```

```css
/* flip the pane when hovered */

.flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}


/* flip speed */

.flipper {
    transition: 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}


/* hide back of pane during swap */

.front,
.back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}


/* front pane, placed above back */

.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}


/* back, initially hidden pane */

.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #fff;
}

.artist-1 {
    background: url(http://img.bleacherreport.net/img/images/photos/003/556/940/edab30087cea36c0ca206fc61a4b10fa_crop_north.jpg?w=630&h=420&q=75) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front artist-1">
            <!-- front content -->
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <p>You won</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front artist-1">
            <!-- front content -->
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <p>You won</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course that's possible, just `removeClass("hover")` for all cards, then add it back for the hovered one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `.toggleClass()` (or `.removeClass()`) to `.hover` element.

```js
$('.flip-container .flipper').on('click',function() {
    // flip back previous hovered element
    if ($('.flip-container.hover').length === 1) {
        // is previous flipped the same as current one?
        var same = $(this).parent().hasClass('hover');

        $('.flip-container.hover').toggleClass('hover');

        var el = $(this);
    
        // flip current element if not the previous one
        if (!same) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                el.closest('.flip-container').toggleClass('hover');
            }, 800);
        }
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.flip-container').toggleClass('hover');
    }
});
```

```css
/* flip the pane when hovered */

.flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}


/* flip speed */

.flipper {
    transition: 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}


/* hide back of pane during swap */

.front,
.back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}


/* front pane, placed above back */

.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}


/* back, initially hidden pane */

.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #fff;
}

.artist-1 {
    background: url(http://img.bleacherreport.net/img/images/photos/003/556/940/edab30087cea36c0ca206fc61a4b10fa_crop_north.jpg?w=630&h=420&q=75) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front artist-1">
            <!-- front content -->
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <p>You won</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front artist-1">
            <!-- front content -->
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <p>You won</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).css('transform, rotateY(180deg)');` may not be useful at all, just `removeClass` and `addClass` does the job...

Comment: This works great can I add some kind of delay so they don't flip simultaneously?

Comment: and I can't flip the card back. It only flips when flipping the other one

Comment: @hcjanni: put line 6 into `setTimeout()`. Timer will be as long as CSS animation.

Comment: `$('.flip-container .flipper').click(function() { 
    // flip back previous hovered element 
    $('.flip-container.hover').toggleClass('hover'); 

    // flip current element 
    setTimeout(3000) 
    $(this).closest('.flip-container').toggleClass('hover'); 
});`

like that?

Comment: @hcjanni: I've updated my answer. On first click it make animation immediately. On second and next click it flips back prev card and after timeout (in my code 500ms) flip current card.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I think you can't manually unflip the card that you flipped right?

Comment: @hcjanni: Everything is possible, I have no time to do that now. Just a hint. Check `if $(this) === $('.flip-container.hover')` and if so just flip card back and don't flip current one.

Comment: Okay, sorry for stealing so much time I'm new to all this but thank you a lot!

Comment: @hcjanni: check my update. It's my last answer, has to go to work :-)